# Glassfish starting with Eclipse always tells: "Wrong user name or password."

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I tried to install a glassfish server, that I would like to use in eclipse.
I have problem with starting the server with jdk 7.
Everything works fine, if i make a glassfish server with my jre6, that
uses jdk6, but i should use jdk7.

So i changed the jre6 to jre7. (But the glassfish starts fine when I use jre6,
but I would like to use jre7.)

Unfortunately I cannot start the glassfish server with jre7, because i always
get a problem:
"Wrong user name or password."

I tried almost everything, but i couldn't solve the problem.

1. I tried to tick "Use anonymous connection for admin commands"
2. I tried to untick it, and use admin-adminadmin, admin-blank, admin-admin identifiers, but it wasn't useful.
3. I tried to reinstall jdk7 and jre7.
4. I tried to start glassfish manually.
5. I tried to start glassfish with undeployed projects.
6. I tried to reinstall new glassfish, varios versions.

I would be very beholden, if somebody could help in my problem.

Comment: Update: Eclipse Plugin did not work with **Glassfish 4.1.1** for me. 
Indeed it worked well with **Glassfish 4.1** and login: admin, password: EMPTY

Comment: just add user "admin"
leave password text-box blank.

Answer (score 6):

try user admin and leave blank field for password. it works for me

Answer (score 0):

The error also occurs if the debug port is wrong.

You should check the vm options of your glassfish too

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

1. Right click the glassfish server in Eclipse
2. Properties
3. Make sure the password is set. Should be the Admin console password.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the properties of your server,

and make

- admin : admin
- password :

(Leave the password as blank )

Answer (score -1):

double click on the Glashfish server
uncheck the checkbox (anonymous user) and provide credentials
it should solve

Kishore